# How to make enemies face player

Tags: flash-cs6, flash-cc, actionscript-3

My game is a simple 2D top down design style. I already have the enemies following the player but i don't know how to make the enemies face him. I don't even know where to begin.

Here's my code to make the enemies follow the player:

```
 if ( enemy.x > player.x ){
      enemy.x -= 7;
 }else {
      enemy.x += 7;
 {
 if ( enemy.y > player.y ){
      enemy.y -= 7;
 }else {
      enemy.y += 7;
 {
```

Comment: Do you want the enemy to face the player exactly (360 degrees) or only the 8 directions your enemy moves?

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have a variable determining the enemy direction. Also, assuming you're just using the four *cardinal* directions.

You can just do a simple comparison of the enemies *x,y* coordinates compared to the player's.

sudo code:

```
if enemy x > player x // player is to the left of the enemy
    enemy face left
else if enemy x < player x // player is to the right of the enemy
    enemy face right
else if enemy y > player y // player is below the enemy
    enemy face down
else
    enemy face up
```

This will make your enemies almost always face left/right. You can get more involved once you get this working by comparing the deltas of the enemy *x/y* compared to the player *x/y*.

Something like:

```
delta x = abs(player x - enemy x)
delta y = abs(player y - enemy y)

if delta x > delta y // Enemy is further away on the x axis than the y axis
    make a choice of facing left/right
else
    make a choice of facing up/down
```

Hope this helps you get started.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the enemy to face exactly toward the player, in other words a full 360 degrees, you can calculate the angle between the `enemy` and the `player` and use the `rotation` property, like this:

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(player.y - enemy.y, player.x - enemy.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
enemy.rotation = angle;
```

For this to look right you should make your `enemy`'s registration to be in its center so that it rotates around its center, and draw it facing rightward so that an angle of 0 is facing right.

Comment: I used this method. The enemy does face the player. But it's not clean and it doesn't always face the player directly                                              var angle:Number = Math.atan2(myCar.y - mc_enemyCar02.y, myCar.x - mc_enemyCar02.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
   mc_enemyCar02.rotation = angle;

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "clean" and "direct", but it *will* always face the player precisely if your `myCar` and `mc_enemyCar` are in the same container. Otherwise you will have to convert your car coordinates to enemy car coordinate space: `var car:Point = enemyCarsContainer.globalToLocal(myCar.localToGlobal(new Point())`. Also make sure your enemy car is drawn *facing rightward exactly.* The math is correct, your graphics might be wrong.